# How to get last salesforce deployment id

Tags: deployment, ant

Hi I am wondering how I can get the last deployment id from Salesforce, it seems the object is DeployRequest but it is not API accessible?

When I get the id manually, I get the sobject type from the id, which returns DeployRequest.

What I have done in my ant script, is to output the deploy to a file, then use regex to get the deployment id, which is not ideal.

Using the migration tool sf deploy will print out the request id.

Is there a better way.

Comment: DeployRequest isn't listed in the [Object Reference](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/object_reference/object_reference.pdf) among the very long list of Standard Objects or their fields.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the object you want is RetrieveResult() and is available through metadata API only.  See [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_asyncresult.htm).

Not sure a call to API is any more effective than parsing it from a file though.

I'm trying to do the same so I can use the ID for a deployRecentValidation action and take advantage of the quick deploy feature.  Curious where you end up and would be helpful if you post back on your eventual/ultimate solution.

Answer (score 1):

I messed around some today and ended up with the below.

It is specific to getting the ID for a validation and reusing that ID for deployRecentValidation but you get the idea.

Because it uses all native ant commands I think it is a more clean/efficient way as compared to having to get a session ID and make a callout to the metadata API, process the result...etc.

```
<target name="validateDeployment">
  <record name="log.txt" action="start"/>
  <sf:deploy username="${sf-target.username}" 
             password="${sf-target.password}" 
             serverurl="${sf-prod.serverurl}" 
             deployRoot="src" 
             checkOnly="true"/>
  <record name="log.txt" action="stop"/>
  <loadfile srcFile="log.txt" property="vid"> 
    <filterchain> 
      <tailfilter lines="1"/>
      <tokenfilter>
        <stringtokenizer suppressdelims="true"/>
        <containsregex pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]{18}"/>
      </tokenfilter>
    </filterchain> 
  </loadfile> 
  <propertyfile file="build.properties" >
    <entry  key="sf-prod.validationID" value="${vid}"/>
  </propertyfile>
</target>
```

Comment: Take care to use the "format code" button to make sure your XML data appears correctly. I've taken care of it for you this time.

Answer (score 1):

1. Once you run 'ant deployCodeCheckOnly' in the Terminal, copy the Request ID. See terminal image below:
   [image: Copy Request ID from Terminal]
2. Paste it in your build.properties file. See Image below:
   [image: Paste Request ID]
3. Save the build.properties
4. Now run 'ant quickDeploy'

It will work!

Comment: just showing a property and not telling where and how its used (in the build.xml) is to a thrash